# How to filter and populate same value in a column in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to achieve the column "Sales = Chair" in power bi. The goal is to filter value for a specific category and populate the value in the rows of the same column.

Category    Subcategory Sales   Sales = Chair

Furniture   Chair       100     100

Furniture   Sofa        150     100

Appliances  Washer      250     100

Appliances  Microwave   200     100

Comment: Can you please show your source and expected data separately? It's bit confusing now.

Comment: Source:- 

Category Subcategory Sales

Furniture Chair     100     

Furniture Sofa             150   

Appliances Washer     250

Appliances Microwave 200

Expected Date :- 
Category Subcategory "Sales = Chair" 

Furniture Chair     100     

Furniture Sofa             100   

Appliances Washer     100

Appliances Microwave 100

Stack doesn't let me post images

Comment: All I'm trying to do is select a specific measure value for sub category and populate the same value in rows in the same column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try a measure like-

```
new_column = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Sales]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Category] = "Furnuture"
            && your_table_name[SubCategory] = "chair"
    )
)
```